# How do I create views in dolphindb?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view, dolphindb

In mysql, I can connect multiple tables or filter some data in a table to create a view. I don't want to damage the data of real tables by manipulating views. I want to create such views in DolphinDB. How should I implement them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

DolphinDB has similar concept, `function view`. A function view can have parameters.